# Mac is mirroring my monitors through miniDP

Tags: displayport, airplay

So I have two DELL u2415 monitors connected to [USC-C to Dual Display Port](https://www.mwave.com.au/product/alogic-usbc-to-dual-displayport-adapter-supports-4k-30hz-ac10000?gclid=Cj0KCQiAiKrUBRD6ARIsADS2OLm8CLMioj8cC4Mr2KuJVivhy_7yEdqvVGugFo36czx9P9Bzzh74onAaAiNoEALw_wcB) adapter. The problem is when I go to displays it shows both my u2415 monitors as one under arrangement and they are just mirroring each other. I think it could be because the adapter is plugged into only the 1 usb-c. Could it be that I need two adapters and for them to not share the same adapter?

Surely there is a way as the adapter was advertised saying it would work.

Anyone had any experiences with an issue like this?

Comment: The advertisement you have referred to only says that this works on Windows - not macOS. Which model of Mac are you using the adapter with?

Comment: @jksoegaard I am using a Macbook Pro (2017 Model) with High Sierra

Comment: Which of the mid-2017 models do you have? - The 13", the 13" with Touch Bar or the 15" with Touch Bar?

Comment: @jksoegaard 15" with touch bar

Answer (score 1):

The adapter in question only supports Windows 10 - it won't work on a Mac.

Connecting two displays via one of the Thunderbolt 3 connectors on the MacBook Pro 15" with TouchBar is usually done via daisy-chaining through the display. This is only supported by Apple for Thunderbolt displays - not DisplayPort monitors.

The cheapest  way to connect your monitors is to use two ports, as you mention. However it is not necessary buying two of those expensive dual-display adapters. Instead you can use a simple USB-C to DisplayPort cable. For example this one:

[https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-DisplayPort-Thunderbolt-Compatible/dp/B01J6DT070/ref%3Das_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&qid=1484165396&sr=8-1&keywords=usbc%20displayport%204k&linkCode=ll1&tag=radianexuscor-20&linkId=a1ef8c98169f6005d21382dca77d66e4&utm_source=tr.im&utm_medium=no_referer&utm_campaign=tr.im%2FCable_Matters_USBC_DP&utm_content=direct_input](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01J6DT070)

Buying two of these ($15.99) will allow connecting the two monitors to your Mac.

Hopefully you can return your adapter for a refund.

Comment: Thanks @jksoeagaard I'll give those cables a shot and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Waiting on new cables and reply from supplier of the initial adapter but weird that it is for a Mac but only supports windows 10...will post their reply here.

Comment: It doesn’t say anywhere that it is for a Mac?